# Using mesh cell highlighting to override the default rendering of a region

Tags: graphics, regions, finite-element-method, mesh

**Bug found in V11 and fixed in V12**

The default rendering of a region can be rather uninformative. Consider this simple example.

```
DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], MaxCellMeasure -> 2]
```

[image: default]

I don't care for this rendering. The edges are hard to see and the vertices are not visible at all. I would prefer it to have it look like this:

[image: desired]

How can such a rendering be accomplished?

Note: The face mesh cells should not be white; they should be transparent (`Opacity[0]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a look at Documentation Center article on DiscretizeRegion, I thought there was a easy solution. I thought it could be done like this:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}],
  MaxCellMeasure -> 2,
  MeshCellHighlight ->
    {0 -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[15], Red],
     1 -> Directive[Thick, Black],
     2 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]}]
```

[image: no_vertex]

But as you can see it didn't work — it failed to highlight the vertex mesh cells. What does work is:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}],
  MaxCellMeasure -> 2,
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {1 -> (Line[#] &), 2 -> (Null &)},
  MeshCellHighlight ->
    {0 -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Red],
     1 -> Directive[Thick, Black]}]
```

[image: desired]

I am troubled by this solution. It doesn't feel right. It doesn't say to me: "Now that you've found me, you see that I'm the obvious solution." In fact, it has more the feel of a work-around for a bug that causes `2 -> RGBColor[0,0,0,0]` to be mishandled. I am also puzzled by the need for `1 -> (Line[#]&)` in the righthand side of the `MeshCellHighlight` option, but here is what happens when it's removed.

[image: no_edges]

I think I should mention that I ran into this strange behavior of `DiscretizeRegion` in V11.3. I would be interested to learn if it persists in V12.

#### Update

I can confirm that the bug described in the question has been fixed in v12 and the work-around given here is no longer needed.

Comment: the issue does not arise in v12.0 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: @kglr. Glad to learn that it's been fixed. I won't bother WRI support people with a bug report.

Comment: What happens if you use `2 -> None` instead of `RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]`?  (Both work in V12, MacOS.)

Comment: @MichaelE2. It produces the same output as `2 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative way via the [finite element mesh visualization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html.en).

Convert your mesh region to an [ElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html):

```
mr = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]];
mesh = mr["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]]
(*ElementMesh[{{0., 2.}, {0., 1.}}, {TriangleElement["<" 2 ">"]}]*)
```

Or you can use the FEM mesh generation directly to generate the mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 2]
```

Then visualize with:

```
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]]]
```

[image]

The default `mesh["Wireframe"]` visualization is close to what you want. We then just add the red nodes. You can find more information in the [finite element mesh visualization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html.en) tutorial.

For those that like more traditional interface to the wire frame can use:

```
Show[
 ElementMeshWireframe[mesh],
 ElementMeshWireframe[mesh, "MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]]
```

Comment: Doesn't this need a definition of `mr`; something like `mr = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], MaxCellMeasure -> 2]`

Comment: I can reproduce your final result using the definition of `mr` I gave in 1st comment, but I don't get the result you show from `mr["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]]`.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. I would have never have thought of applying FE methods. I'm glad you posted it, However, I have to say that it's pretty exotic. Perhaps too exotic for my tastes.

Comment: @m_goldberg, yes, mr = .. is needed, sorry about that. I added an alternative to generate the mesh (I think you are on V11.3, perhaps a bug)

Comment: @m_goldberg, may I ask what makes this exotic for you? The string specification, perhaps, or is it something else?

Comment: Perhaps this is just my taste, but I find `mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]]` to be more readable when written as `mesh@"Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements",  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]` as this emphasizes the fact that it's basically a method call into an object

Comment: @b3m2a1, you can formulate this in several ways, see update.

Comment: @user21 I prefer the method syntax :) I just prefer it using `@` because that looks more like `.` in the other langs I use

Comment: @b3m2a1 and you can do that. No problem.

Comment: @user21. Yes, I'm on V11.3 and it does seem more buggy than V12 when dealing with regions. Your approach seems exotic to me because I no experience in using FE methods. None at all.

Comment: @m_goldberg, OK, got it, thanks.